# spring boot micrometer is already in use by another Collector of type MicrometerCollector

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'm building a micro-service with spring-boot 2.7.8 and spring cloud 2021.0.3(for kafka) and using micrometer(1.9.7) for metrics. when I boot up the service, it fails with the error that tomcat metrics is already registered. I searched for this error and all the reference have been in case of tests not in the actual startup of the app. The detailed error and the error stack is below let me know if you have any suggestion

Error

> Failed to register Collector of type MicrometerCollector:
> xxx_yyyyy_appp_tomcat_global_request_max is already in
> use by another Collector of type MicrometerCollector

Stack

> at
> io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry.register(CollectorRegistry.java:57)
> at io.prometheus.client.Collector.register(Collector.java:308)  at
> io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.lambda$applyToCollector$17(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:561)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1908)
> at
> io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.applyToCollector(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:556)
> at
> io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.newGauge(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:331)
> at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.newTimeGauge(MeterRegistry.java:207)
> at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry$More.lambda$timeGauge$3(MeterRegistry.java:1009)
> at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.lambda$registerMeterIfNecessary$5(MeterRegistry.java:563)
> at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.getOrCreateMeter(MeterRegistry.java:618)
> at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.registerMeterIfNecessary(MeterRegistry.java:570)
> at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.registerMeterIfNecessary(MeterRegistry.java:563)
> at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.access$700(MeterRegistry.java:60)
> at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry$More.timeGauge(MeterRegistry.java:1008)
> at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.TimeGauge$Builder.register(TimeGauge.java:161)
> at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.tomcat.TomcatMetrics.lambda$registerGlobalRequestMetrics$39(TomcatMetrics.java:215)
> at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.tomcat.TomcatMetrics.lambda$registerMetricsEventually$40(TomcatMetrics.java:229)
> at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)   at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.tomcat.TomcatMetrics.registerMetricsEventually(TomcatMetrics.java:229)
> at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.tomcat.TomcatMetrics.registerGlobalRequestMetrics(TomcatMetrics.java:194)
> at
> io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.tomcat.TomcatMetrics.bindTo(TomcatMetrics.java:103)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.tomcat.TomcatMetricsBinder.onApplicationEvent(TomcatMetricsBinder.java:64)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.tomcat.TomcatMetricsBinder.onApplicationEvent(TomcatMetricsBinder.java:42)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:108)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$started$5(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:78)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.started(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:78)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
> at
> xxx.yyyy.aaaaa.appp.Application.main(Application.kt:12)

Comment: Do you happen to use the global registry (Metrics)? Or are you creating your own registry which is not a bean? If so, please don't. Also you can go to start.spring.io and generate a project, that should not have this issue.